# storage device problem

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have InFocus M2-4G mobile.There have no option of 'Default Write Disc'. When installing any apps  it has directly Installed   to the Internal storage after that move it manually  to sd card .but do not directly Installed  to sd card.so
how to directly  install to sd card. Pleas suggest me the details solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Default Write Disk* option is available only when the option is included by your phone's manufacturer. Unless it's included by default, you have to manually move apps to SD card.

If your phone is rooted, there are many apps available in store that does this job. *Link2Sd* is one such app. This app can be used in 2 ways

- Move apps to sdcard automatically/manually
- Create a secondary partition in memory card and link apps to that partition automatically/manually

To automate installation of apps to sdcard, do the following:

1. Goto *Link2sd→Settings*
2. Under *Native App2sd* Settings, select *Install location*
3. Set it to *External*

If you haven't rooted your phone, just Google it